Unable to Determine Path to Powershell Script when deploying CI/CD pipelines in Azure Data Factoy with AzureDevOps
I have been getting some help with deploying pipelines using yaml code with Azure DevOps by a very helpful person called @Alvin.
The problem I'm having is establishing the actual path to certain files - in this case, a Powershell script called pre-and post-deployment.ps1
The code is as follows:
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

When I run the script I get the error:
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'

I'm strugging to establish the actual path to the file.
I have tried to figure out the path using the path details from the following image:

However, the path I used from the image is incorrect, so I don't know how to establish the path.
I was hoping the Job run would show the path, image below. However,the path isn't shown here.

However, there is a way of getting path as shown in following image, however I'm not getting the path in my job run.
https://i.sstatic.net/Tp9fkX7J.png
So, the question is can someone help establish the correct path to the powershell script?
I have modified the script to use adf_publish, and added the tree command, see image, but it still keeps on pointing  main


When I try to switch to adf-publish, see image

I get the following error:

Do I need to manually upload the azure-pipelines-5.yml?
I uploaded the file as suggested by @Wade and it worked :-)

I'm now having a problem with the powershell script itself, see image, but I will raise another ticket for that


As per your yaml, it appears it's main branch, but the file is in adf_publish branch. Please check if the build is executed on correct branch.
With correct branch on my side, the same yaml works for me.
In addition, you can use tree command to get the file list for confirmation.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree


Edit: You are still running on main branch.
If you have the same named yaml in adf_publish branch, simply change the branch to run.

If you don't have the yaml in adf_publish branch, on main branch -> download the yaml file -> go to adf_publish branch, upload the yaml.
After it's done, edit the pipeline to choose the adf_publish branch.


Hi @Wade, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question to reflect your suggestions, but I'm still getting the error

@Patterson, you are still running on main branch, see https://i.sstatic.net/pzcFYGRf.png, please fix it to adf_publish branch. If you don't have yaml in target branch, download the yaml, and upload the yaml to target branch, then edit the pipeline to target branch again.

at present there isn't an azure.yaml my caplogic-warehouse-dev-df. Does that matter?

Hi @Wade, I've updated the question again in response you what you've suggested. Do I need to manually upload the file?

yes, the yaml should exist on the target branch, please upload it.  If you want the yaml on main branch but code on adf_publish branch, you can use repository resource

Your suggestion worked. Thank you very much. This has been a nightmare for me.
